# webservice WSDL import error

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I need help creating a webservice. Basically the company whom im trying to connect with has provided me with a wsdl and xsd files. But when I try to create the web service using the rad webservice widget I get the error below. please help. If you think I need to explain more just ask me dont down vote please!  HELP!

ERROR:

```
Errors occurred during wsimport.
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jdk6.jws22.command.WsImportCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.command.WsImportCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.creation.command.WsimportNonUIThreadCommand$RunCmdInNonUIThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: unresolved reference
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef._get(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef$Type.getType(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.getType(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.xsom.impl.ElementDecl.updateSubstitutabilityMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jdk6.jws22.command.WsimportToolWrapper.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: What are you using, the wsimport tool (in the bin directoy of WAS) or the eclipse wizard?

Comment: @Paul Vargas Im using RAD 8 with WAS 8

Comment: @Paul Vargas I'm using RAD8 with WAS 8..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Java JAX-WS api for webservice skeleton generation insteed of IBM solution you are using right now? There is even `ant task` for such generations, and as far as i know i works quite well (I have used such solutions in my previous workplace). Here you have
[Oracles documentation describing how to use WSIMPORT tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)
or [blog post showing simple usage of WSIMPORT](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/)

Answer (score 2):

For your needs, I'd look at using Maven (since you're using vanilla JAX-WS) with Metro: http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/web_service_tutorial.  Try to stay out of the IDE when creating the JAX-WS artifacts, you'll find most of the headaches are with the IDE rather than the wsimport tool.